# Pass object between before and after advice?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Is it possible to create an object in a before advice and pass it to an after advice? For instance, if I have the aspect:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect {

    pointcut allMethods() : execution(* com.foo.Bar.*(..));

    before() : allMethods() {
        SomeObject foo = makeSomeObject();
    }

    after() : allMethods() {
      // access foo?
    }
}
```

I can't directly reference `foo` since it's not in scope (triggers a compiler error). Is there some context available to both advices that I can store `foo` inside?

Background: I intend to create a unique identifier to refer to this particular invocation of the method and I need access to it in both advices, since I will include it in logging output.

Storing a parameter within my advised class is not an option (since I want it to be unaware of the advice).

Comment: Why don't you use an `around` advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in a member variable, but then you have to think about thread safety. Instead I highly recommend to use an [`around`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) advice.

```
Object around() : allMethods() {
    SomeObject foo = makeSomeObject();
    Object ret = proceed();
    foo.magic();
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it on aspect level exactly as a class member:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect {
    SomeObject foo;
    before() : allMethods() {
        foo = makeSomeObject();
    }

    after() : allMethods() {
      foo.bar();
    }
}
```

According to [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting-development.html#tracing) it should work.

Comment: Are aspects isolated objects? If not this looks so unthreadsafe.

Comment: @Markus Malkusch, I am agree. To make this solution thread-safe I can suggest storing the object in ThreadLocal. However probably solution that you suggested (using around advice) sounds better. Why don't you post it as an answer?