# Pass object between before and after advice

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

My question is the same as in [Pass object between before and after advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339457/pass-object-between-before-and-after-advice), however the accepted answer doesn't work in my case and I would like to ask for some clarification on this topic.

Actually, I'm using `around` advice, but I have to change it. Let's consider an example:

```
public Object registerLog( ProceedingJoinPoint jpoint)
{
    SomeObject so = getSomeData( jpoint.getArgs());
    Object result = jpoint.proceed();
    getMoreData( result, so);
    log( so);
}
```

My `proceed()` method is inserting object into database. In this scenario I'm logging the result of `INSERT` before its transaction commits, which is not very good. That's why I want to split `around` advice into `before` and `after`, so I can log in `after`, when the record is already in database. However, I still need to get some data of the object before it's stored in database.

Of course the solution must be thread-safe, so I can't just add a `SomeObject` member to my aspect class. From the linked question I learned about `ThreadLocal`, and so far it's the best solution I found. However, I never used it before and I would like to ask if there are any other solutions. Maybe there's a way to force a transaction to commit while processing an aspect (I'm not sure right now if this is even a good idea)?

**UPDATE with more details**

I have two pointcuts:

```
<aop:pointcut id="mngrPointcut" expression="execution(* com.mngr.Foo.*(..))"/>
<aop:pointcut id="savePointcut" expression="execution(* com.mngr.Foo.save(..))"/>
```

First pointcut has advice

```
<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="mngrPointcut"/>
```

where advice is

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="select*,search*,get*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

For second pointcut I have aspect

```
<aop:aspect ref="logAspect">
    <aop:around method="registerLog" pointcut-ref="savePointcut"/>
</aop:aspect>
```

When calling `com.mngr.Foo.save()` both pointcuts are valid. Probably because of declaration order, `mngrPointcut` is triggered first, starting a new transaction. Then `savePointcut` is triggered, starting an aspect. As I mentioned above, aspect is responsible for logging. Because of the order in which pointcuts are triggered, object is logged before it is stored in database, which is wrong. I thought that I have to use `before` and `after` advice instead of `around`, so I can call `log()` method in `after` part, when the transaction is already comitted.

Comment: You need to stay with around advice, just make sure your aspect executes before spring's transaction aspect. If you're using aspectj, 'declare precedence' is what you're looking for.

Comment: Why would `around` not work in your case? What could you possible gain from splitting into `before` and `after`? Please elaborate, ideally with some sample code.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Thanks. Setting order of transaction and advice solved the problem. Consider posting it as answer.

Comment: @kriegaex I wanted to control the moment when transaction is comitted and use `after` advice for methods that have to be executed when business object is already in database. Please, check update for some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nándor Előd Fekete's comment, I solved the problem by setting order of transaction and advice. Lower order force aspect to run earlier on the way in and in reverse on the way out. Not ordered aspects run after the one with order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with aspect precedence, changing the pointcut type from `around` to `after` will not help. Instead, you want to make your aspects implement the `Ordered` interface or alternatively annotate them by `@Order`, both as described in the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering). Please also search further down the chapter for the term "ordered" in order (no pun intended) to see some sample code.